# Why would iexplore.exe run Wscript.exe?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In Windows logs, I found that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe` launched `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -dualengineadapter...` which in turn launched `"C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe" "C:\Users\john\Downloads\color.js"`. I'm not allowed to add the content of color.js, but I can tell you what it does. It's a JavaScript file that changes the background color of a span tag and uses various elements' innerHTML to introduce new content. It's very basic, doesn't contain any Windows commands, and I think this came from a user visiting a website.

I cannot find anywhere a reason why IE would use wscript to run JavaScript. Does IE always use wscript.exe to run JavaScript content?

Comment: What's in `color.js`?

Comment: I think that should only happen when hooking into the browser.  For instance a desktop application that embeds the browser as part of it's interface.  When a program launches a browser it can hook functions into it.  If this is from a normal browser launch, the sandbox should prevent any access to windows scripting engine.  (It would use it's own...)

Comment: Please edit the question and add the content of `color.js`

Comment: I've added an explanation of color.js. I think the content is not relevant in this case, because it's a simple JavaScript file which changes various properties of the document object model of a page, I think what matters is that Internet Explorer invokes wscript.exe to run this JavaScript file. I think that maybe it's doing that for every JS file it encounters.

Comment: Color J's could not be JavaScript but Jscript a propietary language

Comment: I confirm that it is JavaScript, the script contains a comment to the script source with the tag <script language="javascript">.